# PYTHON-DOTENV ERROR: no module named 'dotenv'

Tags: python, dotenv

Hello I am creating my website using react.js and python3.8;flask.

But the problem is when I import dotenv, i have this error even though I have installed python-dotenv.

> No module named 'dotenv'

I ran pip install python-dotenv, I tried uninstalling and installing it again but not working

I activated virtual environment, and I can even see dotenv folder that I installed.

here is a piece of my code.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

and this is my requirement.txt file, you can see python-dotenv has been installed.

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
python-dotenv==0.14.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Comment: are you using same python interpreter to run command or you can try if dotenv install or not by checking it in python shell

Comment: Have you tried installing while in the virtualenv?

Comment: @sahasrara62 oh damn. I have been using the same python interpreter in vscode. I uninstalled phthon-dotenv and reinstalled it in a different terminal and it worked. thank you.

Comment: @sooparookie if you are using any IDE better to use virtual env in it so everytime you open project run the code with the virtualenv pythone nv then system one